# How can Ajax do asynchronous request and response a synchronous result

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsonp

I find a fantastic bug when I use jQuery ajax to do a request to web service:

```
var AjaxResult;
login = function () {
    AjaxResult = "";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: KnutBase.getServiceUrl() + "ServiceInterface/HmsPlannerWebService.asmx/AuthenticateLogin",
        data: { username: this.username, password: this.password },
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function (response) {
            //the response value is 'success'
            AjaxResult = response;
        },
        error: function (data, status, e) {
            alert("error:" + e);
        }
    });

    //alert(AjaxResult);
    //if i do not alert a message here, this function will return a null value
    //however, i do alert here, then i get a 'success' value.

    return AjaxResult;
}
```

How could this happen.
I am confused as to why the AjaxResult returns its value before the ajax method set response value to it.

Comment: I don't know from where you have that snippet, but it is just buggy. You are right, it always returns the empty string and this will not change with the async callback.

Comment: Do you have set `{async:false}` in the global ajax default options?

Comment: `method:"POST"` and `dataType:"jsonp"` do not work together; JSONP scripts are always GET requests.

Comment: I have tried  set async:false, but it does not work. I use jquery version 1.8.3. From the latest api, it seems that the async has been deprecated.

Comment: @JackHe: It works, just not with JSONP. And it leaves the browser frozen until it returns, which is why no-one who cares about their users should utilise it.

Comment: @Amadan: if i need the same "async:false" effect for Jsonp, is there any other solution?

Comment: @JackHe: No, jsonp is always asynchronous. And I would not recommend a synchronous way at all, why would you need that? Use the returned Deferred object

Comment: @Bergi As the code show, i just want to get the value from a cross-domain request. However, the asynchronous jsonp make this failed. Put it simply to understand: could you please give me a solution to make the AjaxResult "success" instead of "null". thanks a lot!

Comment: @JackHe: Your request makes as much sense as "Doctor, it hurts me when I chew knives, make it stop". Change the way you're doing things and use a callback - AJAX is not meant to be used synchronously. Think about what you want to do with `AjaxResult` (what you wanted to happen with it *after* you got it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to do with the fact that AJAX is asynchronous (that's actually the meaning of the first A in it). `alert` stops the code until you press the button, and the request has time to complete. With no `alert`, the function proceeds immediately, the AJAX has barely begun its work, and of course the value is still empty.

Generally, you can't have functions return values that they get from AJAX. Set up a callback for it, and deal with it when it comes.

Comment: Amadan  thanks a lot for your answer. Can u give me a simple example"Set up a callback for it".

Comment: if i hope to get the value from the ajax request, can any other way to implement this?

Comment: You will - in the callback. As I said in another comment - what do you want to use it for later? Because returning it from this function is not an option. (Once you answer that, I can give you a more specific answer.)

Comment: thanks Amadan, I think i will use another cross-domain solution. May be policy file.

Answer (score 3):

Ajax is `asynchronous` call to your method and it do the processing in the back for server trip. You will not get the result until the `success` method is called. You can read more about jquery ajax **[here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)**

You can set `async` attribute to `false` of `ajax()` to make a synchronous call.

EDIT: Using deferreds --

[`$.Deferred`](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) can be used to run code after some other code has completed.  Ajax is an excellent example, and all of the jQuery ajax methods (except `.load`) implement the `$.Deferred` interface.  You can use `$.when` to watch deferreds.  For example:

```
login = function () {
   return $.ajax({...
```

The deferred gets returned from the method above, so you can do the following:

```
$.when(login()).done(function (response) { ... });
```

Any code that needs to be synchronized with the ajax response has to go in the `.done` callback.

Note that this is not much different than just using the `success` callback with `$.ajax`.  The point is that all of your work that relies on what is returned from Ajax needs to be done in these callbacks.

Comment: Not with JSONP he can't :p JSONP cannot use `XMLHttpRequest`, so no `async`.

Comment: Hi Amadan. What you answer is right the thing i find. It seems that the datatype"jsonp" can not make a asynchronous call. However, I need jsonp to do a cross-domain request. Do you have any other idea?  thanks

Comment: Hi @JackHe. Yes, I do, and I already said it in too many places: stop trying to return that value. JSONP is fine; but put the code that needs the value into the callback, rather than wait for it when `login` returns. It's the difference between "Go buy salt, I'll wait here twiddling my thumbs; then I'll make dinner" and "Go buy salt, then make dinner when you get it. I'm going to do something else now". Synchronous AJAX is a Bad Idea (TM).

Comment: Thanks Explosion Pills, for editing my answer with useful information, but did you really intend to edit my answer, as your answer is just below my answer and you might be doing edit with yours.

Answer (score 2):

Since ajax is asynchronous, `return AjaxResult` is actually executed before the ajax result completes.  You can not return in this way; you need to perform some action in the callback of the ajax requests or use deferred.

Comment: Could you please give me the example to solve this problem with "deferred"? Thanks really.

Answer (score 1):

> How can Ajax do asynchronous request and return a synchronous result

You can't. It's just impossible. If your code really tries to do that, it will fail.

Comment: [This is incorrect.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=XMLHttpRequest#open%28%29) - `XMLHttpRequest` *can* be made synchronous, it just almost never is because it horribly degrades user experience.

Comment: @Amadan It's clearly correct. If you actually read what they're suggesting, an "asynchronous request" but a "synchronous result"? Not possible. You either make everything synchronous or everything asynchronous. You can't mix them

Comment: …but then Ajax does not do an asynchronous request. Of course one could use Sjax, but that is not discussed in this statement.

Comment: @Ian: Oh, in that sense, yes, he's right - the title is one very confused sentence.

Comment: @Amadan VERY true. Haha I'm not sure what they're exactly looking for with both async _and_ sync...who knows

Comment: sorry for the confused title. To put it simply-- do a cross-domain request and return the result after the request is finished.