# use jQuery to get data from other page

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get data via `$.get` from another page but I can t read the value outside the function. Here is the code I have:

```
$.get('data.php?<?php echo ($params); ?>', null, function(tsv) {
        var lines = [];
        traffic = [];
        try {
            // split the data return into lines and parse them
            tsv = tsv.split(/\n/g);
            jQuery.each(tsv, function(i, line) {
                line = line.split(/\t/);
                date = Date.parse(line[0] +' UTC');
                traffic.push([
                    date,
                    parseFloat(line[1].replace(',', ''), 10)
                ]);
            });
        } catch (e) {  }
        options.series[0].data = traffic;;
    });alert(JSON.stringify(options.series[0].data, null, 4));
```

The problem is that `options.series[0].data` shows null but if I put the alert inside the function tsv, then it shows it fine.

What is going wrong in the code?

Comment: It seems you declared `traffic` as a global variable: `traffic = [];` Do you have any other variable named `traffic` defined outside the function scope?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: AJAX is asynchronous and you're likely firing the alert well before the results have been returned. See this post for more detail - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13966223/how-can-ajax-do-asynchronous-request-and-response-a-synchronous-result

Comment: Ok, I understand. But then how can I execute a script only when I receive all the data from $.get? In fact I need to have 2 different get so I need to wait both of them are finished.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `$.get` or `$.ajax`, you put a callBack function. The data you are getting with "get" you are passing to the function in the variable `tsv`. This variable is only visible from within the function. However, as `$.get` is an asyncronous method, the line of the `alert` is executing before you get the data.

To use the retrieved data from the outside, you must put it in a global variable, use data, or sessionStorage. It all depends on the use you want to do of it.

You could do:

```
var myOptions="";    
$.get('data.php?<?php echo ($params); ?>', null, function(tsv) {
    ....
    options.series[0].data = traffic;
    myOptions=options;
    myStuff();
});

function myStuff(){
    if (myOptions!=="") //chek if has been set
        alert(JSON.stringify(myOptions.series[0].data, null, 4));
}
```